# create table with numerical precision

Tags: mysql, csv, sqlalchemy

Given the following table in csv format:

```
ID,X,Ref_ID
1,42.4242424242,99900000002
```

I use the following script to import this table into a mysql database:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

    import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('MyFile.csv', sep=',')
engine = create_engine('mysql://usr:pass@localhost/mydatabase', echo=False)
df.to_sql("MyTable", engine, index=False)
```

The result:

```
ID: bigint(20)
X: double
Ref_ID : bigint(20)
```

Is there a way to analyse the data and to use exact data types that fit the data? Currently, sqlalchemy seems to create bigint(20) by default for integer columns, and double for columns containing fractional values

What it should have been:

```
ID: int //no need to use a bigint, IDs are not that large
X: decimal(12,10) //This is a geographical coordinate represented by decimal(12,10)
Ref_ID: int(11)
```

Note: I have a lot of columns in my table, so I cannot manually specify the desired data type for each column individually.

For my tables, https://sqlizer.io does produce the desired result, but I would prefer to use a python script instead of depending on a (slow) external website.

Comment: Well you can do a first pass through the csv to figure out the schema first before you import it into the database.